# Function Expected In IE7 & IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, conflict

I am no Javascripter, but I have two Javascripts on my HTML page that are obviously conflicting, I have had a good read through the forum and a good look through google, but can't make out any sufficient solutions, so I am hoping someone here may be able to help me out with their greater experience. I am getting "Function Expected" in IE7 and IE8, later versions of IE are fine, Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera are fine too.

First script:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
});
```

Second script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var quotes = $(".quotes");
var quoteIndex = -1;

function showNextQuote() {
++quoteIndex;
quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .delay(2000)
    .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
}

showNextQuote();

})();
```

I would be extremely grateful for any pointers that you can give me on this.

Comment: in the very last line of your second script, remove the `()` at the end.

Comment: Unless you're going to add a Closure to it, and do `($(document.ready(){`, and then `}(jQuery)` at the end.

Comment: Hi Basilikum thanks for the information, I have tried that and now get an error stating: Object doesn't support this property or method in IE7, but it is now working fine in IE8.I know IE7 is an aging browser and needs retiring, but it would be preferential to have it working in it if I can, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Which jquery version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You're maybe using the jquery version 2.x which doesn't support IE 6,7 or 8. Use the version 1.x instead of 2.x